# Is there a way to report on who Last Published a Knowledge Article?

Tags: reporting, knowledge, custom-report-type, articles

There are a number of fields available for version history tracking on Knowledge Articles, but I am not seeing where we can include who last published an article.

When you look at the Version History for a particular article, you can see publisher info such as "User A published article on Jan 5, 2014 at 7:45 PM"...this info doesn't seem to be available anywhere else.

However, I found the following article that says it should be possible to see the Last Published By info: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hE5oAAE
If it is something that has been delivered, then where can I see this?

Comment: Did you try with LastModifiedBy ? The last person who modified the article will be probably your publisher no ?

Answer (score 2):

See pages 51-52 of the [Summer '12 release notes](http://na9.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_summer12_release_notes.pdf), "Tracking article history events".  Looking at that and the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm), It looks like you'll need to query KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory for history records for the current article version, and look for the history record where the FieldName is "PublishStatus" and the NewValue is "Online".  You'll need to enable history tracking of old and new values for article history.